# Unexpected error displayed when sharepoint list item is created programmatically

Tags: sharepoint

I created a visual web part which let the user select from radio buttons and the clicks on next button ..

Once the button is clicked I wrote a code that create a specific item in a list then redirect the user to a new page

But, when I test it and I clicked on the button, an unexpected error occurred

This is the error

Error

`An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 0a877ec1-b426-486b-a17f-5d576205e686

Date and Time: 10/14/2013 11:47:37 PM`

Any idea about how to fix this problem ??

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way anyone can help you with just the information you've provided. You need to find the corresponding entry in the ULS log file. [The ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) is a very handy tool for doing this. Once you find the specific error, and if that doesn't provide enough information for you to understand your problem, try googling that error. If you're still having problems, please make a new post with that error, along with the important parts of your code.

Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I will use ULS Viewer to know the problem exactly ... But actually I noticed something, and I think maybe this is the problem, the list that I added a new item to it, it's out side the subsite ( it's located in the parent site!) maybe it couldn't    navigate to the site and access it, it seems as an unauthorized !!  Is there a way for sharing a list among a site with its subsites ? And thanks a lot for your answer ^_^

Comment: I don't think it's possible through a Workflow. See [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37497/updating-a-top-level-list-from-a-subsite) for an alternative.

Comment: I just change a little bit on my code and it works fine ^_^.         Thanks for your help